# Look for values and show related codes in other range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2019

I want to search the CODE for each value in
column D. For this I´ve been able to get the formula in E2, getting the output in column E.

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$16,MATCH(D2&"*",$B$1:$B$16,0))
```

- In column A there are CODEs that have a related CODE. The pair relation for each code is in G1:G4
- The `CODE1` could be related with any `NUM`.
- The `CODE2` (those in column H), are related with `NUMs` beginning with `333391`
- Could be several pairs of `CODE1/CODE2` that begin with same 3 characters, due to that I've set the relations in range G:H

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | #### `CODE` | #### `NUM` |  | #### `NUM` | #### `CODE` |  | #### `CODE1` | #### `CODE2` |
| 2 | MMSPL | 1312314 |  | 7965 | FGDYY |  | HHSWA | HHSKQ |
| 3 | MMSPL | 1404725 |  | 120631 | HHSWA |  | FGDYY | FGD95 |
| 4 | HHSWA | 120631 |  | 33339145 | HHSKQ |  | FGDRO | FGDLV |
| 5 | HHSKQ | 33339145 |  | 1404725 | MMSPL |  | MMSPL | MMSQH |
| 6 | HHSWA | 316540 |  | 5275497 | FGDRO |  |  |  |
| 7 | HHSWA | 3460643 |  | 233663 | FGDRO |  |  |  |
| 8 | FGDYY | 7965 |  | 33339100 | FGDLV |  |  |  |
| 9 | FGDYY | 796660 |  | 796660 | FGDYY |  |  |  |
| 10 | FGD95 | 33339183 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 11 | FGDYY | 7967 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 12 | FGDRO | 5199799 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 13 | FGDRO | 233663 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 14 | FGDLV | 33339100 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 15 | FGDRO | 52551223 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 16 | FGDRO | 5275497 |  |  |  |  |  |  |

**My goal is (For Excel 2019):**

If in matches **NUMs**, there is a related **CODE2** as output, then for those **NUMs** that are related with **CODE1**, show as output **CODE2** intead of **CODE1** as shown in "desired output" in image below. how to do this? I hope make sense. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't it be SBD37 for 7965? I mean shouldn't it be same rule applied like for 120631?

Comment: No, for 7965 the match is SBDRU. To get SBD37 would be if the lookup value was 33339183. Since in output there is no SBD37, then don't change the lines with SBDRU. Only change in output all CODE1 values if in output there  is the CODE2.

Comment: Excuse me, but i still don't get it. Then why for 120631 is HHSKQ (code2) and not HHSWA (code1) like for 7965 example?

Comment: @user11222393 For 120631 is HHSKQ (code2) since my desired output is to replace all CODE1 with CODE2, only when at least one CODE2 appears in output. This is, will be a CODE2 if the number to search begins with `333391`. I've edited the current output and desired output with an image in original post I hope make sense. For rows where in output has CODE1 = SBDRU, those are not replaced since there isn't a NUM 333391X to search that matches SBD37.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach checks if the looked-up `CODE` (from column A) exists in column G and, if so, checks if the VLOOKUP of that `CODE`, in columns G & H, is equal to the result below, in which case the result below is returned - otherwise the looked-up code from column A is returned:
[image: Screenshot illustrating suggested formula]
The formula in E2 is

```
=IF(COUNTIF($G$2:$G$5,INDEX($A$1:$A$16,MATCH(D2&"*",$B$1:$B$16,0))),IF(VLOOKUP(INDEX($A$1:$A$16,MATCH(D2&"*",$B$1:$B$16,0)),$G$2:$H$5,2,FALSE)=E3,E3,INDEX($A$1:$A$16,MATCH(D2&"*",$B$1:$B$16,0))),INDEX($A$1:$A$16,MATCH(D2&"*",$B$1:$B$16,0)))
```

which is then copied down.

Since the `INDEX()` function is effectively calculated 4 times for each result, it would be more efficient to employ a helper column, such that the `INDEX()` result could be calculated just once per row, and merely referenced 4 times.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see in your image the output is correct, then don't know why when I try for NUM 5275497 I get FGDRO. Additionally, at beginning I thought it wasn't needed to take in consideration range G:H, but since there are several pairs of codes that begins with same 3 characters, I thought in add the correct relation between each CODE1 and CODE2. I've edited the current output and desired output with an image in original post

Comment: @RasecMalkic, 5275497 will return FGDRO only until there is a formula entered in E8 (this is a function of how you have ordered the data - with the `333391` _NUM_ appearing at the _end_ of related _NUMs_, rather than at the _beginning_). If there are several pairs of codes beginning with the same 3 characters then please edit your question to show this - your sample data are misleading otherwise.

Comment: I've modified the sample data to consider that there are severals codes beginning with same 3 characters.

Comment: @RasecMalkic, answer updated with revised (& longer) formula

Comment: Thanks so much. Very complex formula to me. For thousands of rows I'll consider your suggestion of a helper column I think.

Comment: @RasecMalkic Now that you have MS365 you can benefit from a much shorter formula: `=LET(idx,INDEX($A$1:$A$16,MATCH(D2:D9&"*",$B$1:$B$16,0)),IF(COUNTIF($G$2:$G$5,idx),IF(VLOOKUP(idx,$G$2:$H$5,2,FALSE)=E3:E10,E3:E10,idx),idx))` (& no need for helper column)